# How can I make it so that a function dynamically adjusts one of its parameters based on what its output will be?

Tags: python, chess

I am making a chess engine and need for a slice function to change depending on how many numbers are following the beginning of the split (or any other method that accomplishes the same). So that the program knows how many times to repeat displaying a piece. Eg this is the standard chess setup; bRbNbBbQbKbBbNbR**8**bP**32**EE**8**wPwRwNwBwQwKwBwNwR

This is my code so far;

chessEngine.py

```
colours = ["White", "Black"]

class gameState():
    def __init__ (self):
        self.board = "bRbNbBbQbKbBbNbR8bP32EE8wPwRwNwBwQwKwBwNwR"
        self.moveColour = "White"
        self.gameLog = ""
        self.canCastle = True
```

chessMain.py

```
import pygame
import chessEngine

pygame.init()
WIDTH = HEIGHT = 512
DIMENSION = 8
SQ_SIZE = HEIGHT // DIMENSION
MAX_FPS = 5
IMAGES= {}

def loadImages():
    pieces = ["bR", "bN", "bB", "bQ", "bK", "bP", 
              "wP", "wR", "wN", "wB", "wQ", "wK",]
    for piece in pieces:
        IMAGES[piece] = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load("Assets/" + piece + ".png"), (SQ_SIZE,SQ_SIZE))
        """ 
    We can now access an image by saying "IMAGES()"
    eg; to get the image for a white pawn write "IMAGES["wP"]"
    """
def main():
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    screen.fill(pygame.Color("white"))
    gs = chessEngine.gameState()
    loadImages()
    running = True
    while running:
        for x in pygame.event.get():
            if x.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
        drawGameState(screen, gs)
        clock.tick(MAX_FPS)
        pygame.display.flip()

def drawGameState(screen, gs):
    drawBoard(screen)
    drawPieces(screen, gs.board)

def drawBoard(screen):
    colors = [pygame.Color(253,235,253), pygame.Color(75,160,60)] # White and green
    for r in range(DIMENSION):
        for c in range (DIMENSION):
            color = colors[((r+c)%2)]
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, pygame.Rect(c*SQ_SIZE, r*SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))

def drawPieces(screen, board):
    squareCount = 0
    listCount = 0
    r = squareCount % DIMENSION
    c = squareCount // DIMENSION
    for z in range(DIMENSION^2):
        x = slice(listCount, listCount + 1)
        if board[x].isnumeric() == False:
            v = slice(listCount, listCount + 2)
            screen.blit(IMAGES[board[v]], pygame.Rect(r*SQ_SIZE, c*SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))
            squareCount += 1
            listCount += 2
        else:
            amount = int(board[x])
            for y in range(amount):
                v = slice(listCount, listCount + 2)
                screen.blit(IMAGES[board[v]], pygame.Rect(r*SQ_SIZE, c*SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))                
                squareCount += 1
            listCount += len(str(amount)) + 2      

    
main()
```

Comment: This is called "run-length encoding".  There's no shortcut.  For each element, you can't write anything until you read the NEXT element.  At that point you can decide whether it is time to write out the last one, or just accumulate the count until next time.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do run-length encoding of your board:

```
import csv

board = [
 ['bR','bN','bB','bQ','bK','bB','bN','bR'],
 ['bP','bP','bP','bP','bP','bP','bP','bP'],
 ['EE','EE','EE','EE','EE','EE','EE','EE'],
 ['EE','EE','EE','EE','EE','EE','EE','EE'],
 ['EE','EE','EE','EE','EE','EE','EE','EE'],
 ['EE','EE','EE','EE','EE','EE','EE','EE'],
 ['wP','wP','wP','wP','wP','wP','wP','wP'],
 ['wR','wN','wB','wQ','wK','wB','wN','wR']
]

def rle(board):
    last = None
    count = 0
    s = ''
    for row in board:
        for cell in row:
            if cell == last:
                count += 1
            else:
                if last:
                    if count > 1:
                        s += str(count)+last
                    else:
                        s += last
                count = 1
                last = cell
    if count > 1:
        s += str(count)+last
    else:
        s += last
    return s

print(rle(board))
```

Output:

```
bRbNbBbQbKbBbNbR8bP32EE8wPwRwNwBwQwKwBwNwR
```

Answer (score 0):

Below, I'm assuming you know about the standard [Forsyth–Edwards Notation (FEN)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation) and don't want to use it. If you do, check out the [chess](https://pypi.org/project/chess/) package, which abstracts such details away.

```
Starting position
-----------------
FEN notation:              rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1
Your custom notation:      bRbNbBbQbKbBbNbR8bP32EE8wPwRwNwBwQwKwBwNwR
```

Just a tip, not a direct answer to your question - you could borrow FEN's convention of using upper- and lowercase letters for white and black pieces to get even higher compression:

```
Improved custom notation:  rnbqkbnr8p32e8PRNBQKBNR
```